# Excel - Dynamic Charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I have a series that looks like `SERIES('Data'!$C$140;'Data'!$E$138:$Q$138;'Data'!$E$140:$Q$140;2)` and in order to make it dynamic I'd like to replace the endpoints with a cell that depends on the start point, like this:
`SERIES('Data'!$C$140;'Data'!$E$138:OFFSET($E$140;0;12);'Data'!$E$140:OFFSET($E$140;0;12);2)`

But this is not working. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

It turns out that `OFFSET()` is not allowed in a `SERIES()` function. Neither is `INDEX()`. Even with the corrections below, your technique won't work to make the chart dynamic.

However, there are two other ways to make dynamic charts:

1. Using a Table as the data source when creating the chart.
2. Using a dynamic Named Formula for each of the series.

See [this site](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/two-ways-to-build-dynamic-charts-in-excel/) for a tutorial on applying these two methods.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

You have two issues that I can see.

For starters, you have a typo. The first argument of the first `OFFSET()` should be `$E$138`  not `$E$140`.

Secondly, you're missing the sheet references for the first arguments of both `OFFSET()` functions.

If the operand after the `:` operator is a hard-coded value, like the `$Q$138` in `'Data'!$E$138:$Q$138`, a sheet reference for it is not required. If the operand is a function, then the same sheet reference as used for the operand before the `:` must be used for the reference returned from the function.

The corrected formula is:

```dart
SERIES('Data'!$C$140;'Data'!$E$138:OFFSET('Data'!$E$138;0;12);'Data'!$E$140:OFFSET('Data'!$E$140;0;12);2)
```

Comment: Thank you. It still doesn't work. I get the following error: https://imgur.com/a/U8NLrMJ

Comment: @user919640 Oops! Sorry. Should have actually tried the formula. Turns out your technique is flawed. I've updated the answer with two alternatives.